# Extract an element from XML using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql, xml-parsing

I had a situation

- Xml execution plan stored in a table
- Need to filter ColumnReference element and its attributes from xml plan

Sample element

```
<ColumnReference Database="[Adventureworks]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Product]" Column="ProductID" />
```

challenge : `ColumnReference` is available in multiple hierarchy, need to extract all of them

Expected output as table in below structure:

```
Database | Schema | Table | Column
```

Sample Dataset: (run below code you will get dataset in temptable called #t)

```
    CREATE TABLE Employee 
    (
        EmpID INT NOT NULL , 
        EmpName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
        Designation VARCHAR(50) NULL, 
        Department VARCHAR(50) NULL, 
        JoiningDate DATETIME NULL,
        CONSTRAINT [PK_Employee] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (EmpID)
    )

    INSERT INTO Employee 
    (EmpID, EmpName, Designation, Department, JoiningDate) VALUES 
    (1, 'CHIN YEN', 'LAB ASSISTANT', 'LAB', GETDATE()),
    (2, 'MIKE PEARL', 'SENIOR ACCOUNTANT', 'ACCOUNTS', GETDATE()),
    (3, 'GREEN FIELD', 'ACCOUNTANT', 'ACCOUNTS', GETDATE()),
    (4, 'DEWANE PAUL', 'PROGRAMMER', 'IT', GETDATE()),
    (5, 'MATTS', 'SR. PROGRAMMER', 'IT', GETDATE()),
    (6, 'PLANK OTO', 'ACCOUNTANT', 'ACCOUNTS', GETDATE())
create proc itemployee
as 
select EmpName, Designation  from Employee where department = 'it'

go 

exec itemployee


SELECT 
  'itemployee ' as SP_Name, 
  query_plan into #t  FROM sys.dm_exec_cached_plans cp CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_query_plan(cp.plan_handle)
WHERE 
  object_id('itemployee') = objectid;
```

query used to extract the output:

```
SELECT 
  AnyColRef.value('@Table', 'nvarchar(250)') AS [Table], 
  AnyColRef.value('@Column', 'nvarchar(250)') AS [Column] 
FROM 
  #t t
  CROSS APPLY t.query_plan.nodes('//ColumnReference') A(AnyColRef);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you provide is not enough... For your next question please try to create a [mcve (a *stand-alone* sample to reproduce your issue)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

> challenge : ColumnReference is available in multiple hierarchy, need to extract all of them

As a quick shot you might try something along this:

```
SELECT AnyColRef.value('@Database','nvarchar(250)') AS [Database]
      ,AnyColRef.value('@Schema','nvarchar(250)') AS [Schema]
      ,AnyColRef.value('@Table','nvarchar(250)') AS [Table]
      ,AnyColRef.value('@Column','nvarchar(250)') AS [Column]
FROM YourTable t
CROSS APPLY t.YourXMLColumn.nodes('//ColumnReference') A(AnyColRef);
```

The idea in short:
The *deep search* (triggered by the doubled slash at `//ColumnReference`) will search for any element with this name anywhere in your XML. All these elements are returned as a *derived set*, where each element comes back in its own row (this is done by `.nodes()`). The native XML method `.value()` will finally retrieve the iternal values of the attributes (indicated by the `@`).

### UPDATE

Best was to provide a sample of XML you want to read, but thx for the code above to reproduce your issue, it helped too.

Your issue is: The XML is declaring a default namespace. There are three approaches to deal with this:

1. a) Use `WITHXMLNAMESPACES` with a prefix
2. b) Use `WITHXMLNAMESPACES` with `DEFUALT`
3. a) Use an internal declaration with prefix
4. b) Use an internal declaration for `default element namespace`
5. Use a wildcard

Either this

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES('http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/07/showplan' AS ns)
SELECT
  AnyColRef.value('@Table', 'nvarchar(250)') AS [Table], 
  AnyColRef.value('@Column', 'nvarchar(250)') AS [Column] 
FROM 
  #t t
  CROSS APPLY t.query_plan.nodes('//ns:ColumnReference') A(AnyColRef);
```

--Or this

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/07/showplan')
SELECT
  AnyColRef.value('@Table', 'nvarchar(250)') AS [Table], 
  AnyColRef.value('@Column', 'nvarchar(250)') AS [Column] 
FROM 
  #t t
  CROSS APPLY t.query_plan.nodes('//ColumnReference') A(AnyColRef);
```

--Or this

```
    SELECT
      AnyColRef.value('@Table', 'nvarchar(250)') AS [Table], 
      AnyColRef.value('@Column', 'nvarchar(250)') AS [Column] 
    FROM 
      #t t
      CROSS APPLY t.query_plan.nodes('declare namespace ns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/07/showplan";//ns:ColumnReference') A(AnyColRef);
```

--Or this

```
    SELECT
      AnyColRef.value('@Table', 'nvarchar(250)') AS [Table], 
      AnyColRef.value('@Column', 'nvarchar(250)') AS [Column] 
    FROM 
      #t t
      CROSS APPLY t.query_plan.nodes('declare default element namespace "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/07/showplan" ;//ColumnReference') A(AnyColRef);
```

--Or this

```
SELECT
  AnyColRef.value('@Table', 'nvarchar(250)') AS [Table], 
  AnyColRef.value('@Column', 'nvarchar(250)') AS [Column] 
FROM 
  #t t
  CROSS APPLY t.query_plan.nodes('//*:ColumnReference') A(AnyColRef);
```

The general advise is: Be as specific as possible. Namespaces are not just a fancy add-on, but very import to deal with different elements with identical names (often when various XMLs are combined). Use the *easy-cheesy* wildcard only in cases where you can be sure, that the namespace is not needed. Personally I prefer the approach `WITH XMLNAMESPACES` with `DEFAULT` as it is the closest to the given XML.

Comment: your query returns nothing. have added sample data  for your reference

Comment: if possible please share some url to learn about xml processing in sql